# How to search for a specific (five) digit number in RegEx? (Notepad++)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'd like to know, how to search for a five digit number in RegEx, in Notepad++. (Please make sure, that your answer, WORKS in Notepad++ 8.4.6

I'm looking for **Notepad++** specific answers. **NOT** general **RegEx** answers. I'd like to know, how to find (example) 14000 in RegEx, in Notepad++. It has to be: 1. RegEx, 2. Notepad++

When you press "Ctrl + F" in Notepad++

[image]

**Example:**

Let's say I want to look for all numbers in the .txt file, which are above 14000.

How can I search for it, using RegEx, in Notepad++?

(Please provide a specific example, for 14000, for 14410 and for any five digit number, (and if you are very kind, one for a four digit number)).

Comment: See [my "Matching custom numeric ranges" YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSGq5rHIINs). I have shared a numeric range regex generator that can help with patterns like this, too, you will just need to edit the pattern later.

Comment: I'd like to know, how to find it, in Notepad++ (not programming language, not anywhere else, but in Notepad++, when you press Ctrl+F. Make sure your answer works, and you tried it, before posting here. (Someone marked this question as a "duplicate", I hope I made my point clear, that I want it in specifically, Notepad++. Thanks!)